# Usage of clickhousehook Python

Tags: python, select, connection, clickhouse

I'm beginner in python and I need to define connection for ClickHouseHook operator. Can you please provide correct format connection string which should be putted into clickhouse_conn_id=:

```
from airflow_clickhouse_plugin.hooks.clickhouse_hook import ClickHouseHook

def _data_from_clickhouse():
    ch_hook = ClickHouseHook(**clickhouse_conn_id=''**)
    ch_hook.get_records('select * from table')
```

Didn't find right connection string format in web